# Is there a Moria like theme for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, text-editor, color-scheme

Is there some cool [Moria](http://winterdom.com/2007/04/visualstudiomoriaalternate) like theme for Visual Studio 2010?

[image]

Mine is highlighting gray font with gray background!

I just can't configure it on Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors menu. Visual Studio doesn't seem to show an item for this "highlighting keyword/tag system". You select a variable on variable called myVar, and it highlights all with the same name but with a grayer color and gray background. I just can't read it and can't set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color you're searching for is called "Highlighted Reference" in the options.

Fore some VS styles, see http://studiostyles.info/